# How does a volatility surface based on moneyness instead of strike stay consistent with put-call parity?

Tags: implied-volatility, volatility-smile

By definition due to put-call parity the implied volatility will be the same for puts and calls with the same strike price and time to maturity. Meanwhile, a volatility surface is often quoted in terms of moneyness and maturity rather than strike and maturity. So one node will correspond to e.g 1 year maturity and 1.25 moneyness. Now I take moneyness to mean S/K for a call, and K/S for a put, but for a given spot price S this would give different values of K for puts and calls. Say S=1.25 we have that K=1 for the call option, and K = 1.25^2=1.5625 for the put. Now this could hold of course with a slightly asymmetrical smile centered around K=1.25, but does this really always hold? I would think that the shape of the smile and put-call parity are completely unrelated. Perhaps I'm interpreting moneyness the wrong way?

Comment: I think the issue may be resolved when using logarithmic moneyness, i.e. $\log(F/X)$.

Comment: I don't see how. Could you provide a calculation example?

Comment: If your call has a moneyness $m=\log(105/100)\approx 0.05$ then the corresponding put has a moneyness of approx. $-0.05$ and the two options would be *tied* by Put-Call-Parity, no?

Comment: @Kermittfrog Hmm, not sure. How about we frame it another way: Say we are creating the surface and want to create the node with 0.05 log moneyness, we would look for the call with a strike that satisfies 0.05=log(S/K), which is S=105 would give K = exp(0.05)*105=110.38. We could also look for a put with a strike that satisfies 0.05=log(K/S) which leads to K=99.87. So then we would have that sigma(K=99.87)=sigma(K=110.38) which makes a perfectly pretty smile so it's not unreasonable, but there's nothing that says we *need* to have a perfect smile like this which this method seems to assume.

Comment: I think you are using call and put convention at the same time, i.e. forward call moneyness = $F/K$ whereas forward put moneyness = $K/F$. I would stick with one notation, i.e. a forward call moneyness of $m=ln(F/K)$ equals a forward put moneyness of $-m$. And $C(m)+Ke^{-rt}=P(m)+S$. Does that work?

Comment: I see, yes that would clear it up I think since log(S/K) = -log(K/S). In that case my second calculation becomes -0.05=log(K/105) which gives the same value of K=110.38.

I suppose the same convention should be used when dealing with moneyness (not log moneyness) so if you have a (call) moneyness of 1.25 you should look at a put with 1/1.25=0.8 moneyness to get the same node on the surface. I would assume that when a surface is listed with moneyness on the axis then it is call moneyness that is meant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a moneyness surface, moneyness is usually defined the same way for calls and puts. I have seen in [another question from you](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/59596/54838) that you use Bloomberg. On `OVDV`, moneyness is defined as K/S. Your screenshot from the linked question shows spot is 1814.79; since you ticked *Strikes*, you can also see the corresponding strikes (highlighted in Red right underneath the moneyness levels):
[image]

Therefore,

- $\color{grey}{100 \% \ moneyness}$: (also called At-the-money-Spot ATMS) is displayed as 1814.8.
- $\color{blue}{<100 \% \ moneyness}$: This corresponds to OTM Puts (ITM Calls) - for example 90% moneyness corresponds to a strike of 1633.3 (90% of 1814.8),
- $\color{YellowGreen}{>100 \% \ moneyness}$: This corresponds to OTM Calls (ITM Puts) - 105% is 1905.5 and so forth.

OVME allows you to display moneyness in a different way relative to ATM, in terms of ITM (OTM), but it is essentially the same. The screenshot below corresponds to a Spot of 3166.48.

[image]

- 1373.28 is 56.63% ITM for a call ($1- 1373.28/3166.48$, where $1373.28/3166.48 \approx 42.37 \%$ moneyness on OVDV)
- 2746.56 is 13.26% OTM for a put ($1- 2746.56/3166.48$, where $2746.56/3166.48 \approx 86.76 \%$ moneyness on OVDV)

So, each moneyness level corresponds to one strike - and put and call for the same strike have the same vol. You can look at [Is it possible to have only one volatility surface for American options (that fits both calls and puts)](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/73861/54838) to see why OVDV shows only one surface for calls and puts?